# Active Directory query troubleshooting

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My customer uses the below query to pull the data from Active Directory into my application.

CN=WebCalAdmin,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=hasm,DC=com

and getting the below error.

Error: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

I need to replicate the same issue in my lab environment. I have created OU's in my test active directory. But I am not sure how to create CN=WebcalAdmin in my test active directory.

Is CN and OU are same? What is the difference between CN and OU?
What are the steps to create CN=WebCalAdmin in my Active Directory?

Thanks in Advance,
Siva.S.

Answer (score 4):

**CN** stands for `common name` and is used to identify users, groups and computers in your LDAP string.

**OU** stands for `organizational unit` and is used to identify OU's that acts as containers inside which other objects can live - e.g. the divisions, departments, etc. of your organization used to create a hierarchy and a structure.

So these two are totally different - OU's are used to build up a tree of nested containers for objects like users, groups, computers.

Comment: So CN common name is same as that of group name created in Active directory right?

Comment: Yes, if you specify "MyGroup1" in Active Directory Users & Computers when you create the group, the group's full LDAP path will be `cn=MyGroup1,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=hasm,DC=com` (or something else depending on where you create that group in)

Answer (score 3):

OU is created through AD Users and Computers tool - by clicking on New->Organization Unit and a CN node is created by doing New->User or New->Computer as needed.

If you are using softerra LDAP Admin tool then you need to do New Entry on the node and select the user/computer or your own custom schema class to proceed. You can also do this using ldif import command : ldifde.

CN is the leaf entry and can only have another CN under it. So you can have a CN under OU but not other way round.